# export array with Hooks in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am trying to export an array I am generating in a function, so that I can use it in my main component.  I have the following code :-

ChildComponent:-

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const DeckFootball = () => {
    const [ fullDeck, setFullDeck ] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        generateDeck()
    }, [deck])

    const deck = []
    const deckLimits = {
        joker: 4,
        goalkeepers: 12,
        defenders: 12,
        midfielders: 12,
        attackers: 12,
      }

      const generateDeck = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.joker; i++) {
          generateCard("joker")
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.goalkeepers; i++) {
          generateCard("goalkeeper")
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.defenders; i++) {
          generateCard("defender")
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.midfielders; i++) {
          generateCard("midfielder")
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.attackers; i++) {
          generateCard("attacker")
        }
        setFullDeck(deck);
      }
    
      const generateCard = item => {        
        const card = {...}
    
        //add this card to the deck
        deck.push(card)
      }      
    
    return [fullDeck];

}

export default DeckFootball;
```

Then in my main component, I am doing the following:-

MainComponent:-

```
import {fullDeck} from '../../decks/football/deck_football';
```

When I `console.log(fullDeck)` this is `undefined`

Is my syntax wrong?  Seems like the child component is not being called.

I also tried

```
import DeckFootball, {fullDeck} from '../../decks/football/deck_football';
```

and then `console.log(DeckFootball.fullDeck)` but that is also undefined.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's a confusion here. What you are exporting has the syntax of a Component, you mention it's a hook (its name should begin with `use` to be a hook) and you're rendering some static data I believe. If that's your case, a plain javascript function will do the trick for you, you don't need anything React related here

```
export const buildDeck = () => {
  const deck = []
  const deckLimits = {
    joker: 4,
    goalkeepers: 12,
    defenders: 12,
    midfielders: 12,
    attackers: 12,
  }
  const generateCard = item => {        
    const card = {...}

    //add this card to the deck
    deck.push(card)
  }      
  

  for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.joker; i++) {
    generateCard("joker")
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.goalkeepers; i++) {
    generateCard("goalkeeper")
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.defenders; i++) {
    generateCard("defender")
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.midfielders; i++) {
    generateCard("midfielder")
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.attackers; i++) {
    generateCard("attacker")
  }
  
    
  return fullDeck;
}
```

You don't need a React component because you're not doing anything UI related.

What your current code does does not require any state or effect, because there's nothing that needs to react or be updated during the lifecycle of your app - so you don't need it to be a hook either

You could just import this function like this

```
import { buildDeck } from 'the/path'
```

of it (and you will reference the same result on every render - which make sense as it looks like it is static data)

For instance

```
const Mycomponent = () => {
  // inside render - it will be build on every render. You might be ok or not with that
  const fullDeck = buildDeck()
}
```

or

```
// outside render - it will be build just once
const fullDeck = buildDeck()
const Mycomponent = () => {
  //  you can log it on every render, but it will be referencing the exact reference of the same deck on every render
  console.log(fullDeck)
}
```